# Adding DRL resources without workbench to Kieserver

Tags: microservices, drools, jbpm, drools-kie-server

Is there a way to deploy drool files in kieserver without using workbench ? I want to create DRL files using eclipse IDE and deploy/execute rule definitions via HTTP/REST on stand alone kieserver.

Comment: I was able to solve this using kie-server-spring-boot-starter-drools

Answer (score -1):

Using kie-server-spring-boot-starter-drools I was able to setup a service packaging rule definition as DRL and invoke through HTTP/Rest post call on kieserver